# JSON value to be print by Python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have created a script where I need to get each details of user that is being generated in JSON. What could be the possible way in order for me display the `"name": "admin"`?

Please see script below.
`

```
import xmlrpc.client
import json
class TestlinkAPIClient:        
    # substitute your server URL Here
    SERVER_URL = "https://testserver"
    def __init__(self, devKey):
        self.server = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy(self.SERVER_URL)
        self.devKey = devKey
    def getUserByLogin(self):
        for userDetail in self.server.tl.getUserByLogin(dict(devKey=self.devKey,user='user1')):
            user_status = int(userDetail.get("isActive")) #json(userDetails.json) value isActive = 1 else isActive = 0 for not active
            lastname = userDetail.get("lastName")
            firstname = userDetail.get("firstName")
            userLogin = userDetail.get("login")
            activeStatus = ("Active User")
            globalrole = userDetail.get("globalRole")
            tproject = userDetail.get("tprojectRoles")
            #for role in tproject.values():
            for projectID in tproject:
                user_detail = (userLogin + " " + lastname + " " + firstname + " " + str(globalrole['name']) + " " + "ProjectID: " + projectID)
                print(user_detail)
# substitute your Dev Key Here
client = TestlinkAPIClient("testlinkApiKey")
details = client.getUserByLogin()
with open('./DebugProjectRoleDetails.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(details , f)
```

and here is the sample json format, hhere I should get an output of the `"name": "admin"`

```
[
{
    "firstName": "UserFirst",
    "lastName": "UserLast",
    "emailAddress": "first.last@morpho.com",
    "locale": "fr_FR",
    "isActive": "1",
    "defaultTestprojectID": "",
    "globalRole": {
        "name": "projectadmin",
    }
    "globalRoleID": "10",
    "tprojectRoles": {
      "1234": {
        "name": "admin"
    }
```

}
]

expected output:
`0001 User projectadmin ProjectID: 1001 projectRoles=viewer`

Answer (score 1):

If userDetail is in a JSON file and you want to save it as a dictionary, so you can use the get() method, you need to use json.load:

```py
   import json

   with open('./user.json') as f:
       details = json.load(f)
```

Since tproject is also a dictionary you need to use get() to extract the role (value) corresponding to the project (key)

```py
   for userDetail in details:
       user_status = int(userDetail.get("isActive"))
       lastname = userDetail.get("lastName")
       firstname = userDetail.get("firstName")
       userLogin = userDetail.get("login")
       activeStatus = ("Active User")
       globalrole = userDetail.get("globalRole")
       tproject = userDetail.get("tprojectRoles")
       # for role in tproject.values():
    for projectID in tproject:
        role = tproject.get(projectID)
        user_detail = f"{userLogin} {lastname} {firstname}  {str(globalrole['name'])} ProjectID:  {projectID} {role}"
        print(user_detail)
```

ouput using your JSON sample:

```
 None UserLast UserFirst  projectadmin ProjectID:  1234 {'name': 'admin'}
```

Comment: now, how can I call `"name": "admin"` under tprojectRoles:{"7293":{"name": "admin"}

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that it is possible to declare 2 items in a for loop.

```
dictionary_item_tproject = tproject.items()
        for projectID,projectRole in dictionary_item_tproject:
            print(userLogin + " " + lastname + " " + firstname + " " + str(globalrole['name']) + " " + str(projectID) + " " +str(projectRole['name']))
```

This solve my problem. Now I am able to parse JSON properly. Thanks everyone.